# Eager loading erorr Call to undefined method grammer question in Laravel 6

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is my first time to try out Eager loading.

Here is my controller code.
I add 'WITH' into my code but I got this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::with()
```

I've been searching how to put WITH. but I've got error always. Could you teach me right code please?

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $products = Product::with(All());

        $products = DB::with('products')
        ->join('creators', 'creators.id', '=', 'products.creator_id')
        ->join('categoris', 'categoris.id', '=', 'products.categori_id')        
        ->join('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'products.br_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
        ->get();
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'index',
            'no'    => 1,
            'products'  => $products,
        );
        return view('product.index',$data);
    }
```

Update

Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','kansu','creator_id', 'br_id','user_id' ,'categori_id'];
    
    public function index()
    {               
        return $this->belongsTo('Categori');
    }

}
```

Categori

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categori extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['pr_name'];
    
    public function index()
    {       
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }
}
```

UPDATE

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `with` eager loading is used with [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).which means you first need define model like `Product` model here,and you need define relation between models like `belongsTo` `hasMany`.
for example

- we had define two models `Product` and `Category`
- we define the relation,Product `belongsTo` Category
- then we can call `Product::with('category')` with eager loading

the `DB::` method is only used in [laravel database](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) for lower level database operation,there is no model concept at `DB::` method,you can directly use `DB::` to construct the raw sql you want

the example of relation define

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title','kansu','creator_id', 'br_id','user_id' ,'categori_id'];
    public function categor(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categori::class);
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categori extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['pr_name'];
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'categor_id');
    }
}
```

be aware of the `foreign key` and `local key`

> Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the parent model name. In this case, the Phone model is automatically assumed to have a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method

you can read the laravel [relation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) document

Comment: @Dear nay Thank you very much for helping me. 
I see I need to add some code into Models! I tried and I update current code. I'm not sure where to put function... I got syntax error now. Could you take a look them please?

Comment: I had update my answer add example on how to define relation,and the laravel document is very readable,you will get more details in it

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try lest of it by myself. I really learned how to write models. Thank you!